# SolrQuery not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, solr, solrnet

I have uploaded some product data to solr and trying to retrieve it through SolrNet query.
when i use `SolrQueryByField` its working good and when i use simple `SolrQuery` its not returning any data
**Working code**

```
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("id", "SP2514N"));
```

**Not working Code**

```
          var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
          var results = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("SP2514N"));
```

I can't understant why this is not working.Can any one give a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Query `SolrQueryByField("id", "SP2514N")` would fire the query the `id` field with `SP2514N` .

For the Query `SolrQuery("SP2514N")` would fire the query the default field with `SP2514N` .
The default field is usually defined as text which may not have a match.

Comment: Can you tell me What Else I need to do in order to make a simple query with out any filed name?